# Sorting multiple columns with delimiter "." in bash

Tags: bash, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of text that looks like this:

```
2023.12.14
2020.10.4
2020.10.1
2020.5.18
2023.14.1
2021.1.1
```

desired output:

```
2020.5.18
2020.10.1
2020.10.4
2021.1.1
2023.12.14
2023.14.1
```

I tried to achieve it with the following command:

`sort -t "." -k1,1 -k2,1 -k3,1  sortingTest.txt`

With this command I'm trying to sort it by the first "column" (anything before the delimiter "."), and in case that two values are equal than compare the values of the second column etc.

For some reason it only sorts by comparing values of the first column.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a few problems, the `-k` is defined as: `-kfield1[,field2]`, which means `-k2,1` is invalid. You can use `-k1 -k2 -k3` to sort on the first three fields.

You properly want to do numeric sort on your fields, this can be enabled with `-n` see `man 1 sort` for other numeric sorting options:

```
$ sort -t. -n -k1 -k2 -k3 file.txt
2020.5.18
2020.10.1
2020.10.4
2021.1.1
2023.12.14
2023.14.1
```

Might work for you.

In case these are actually versions and not dates, then `-V` might be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. -V seems to be sufficient. When I try your command ``` sort -t. -n -k1 -k2 -k3 ´´´ the line 2020.5.18 actually appears after 2020.10.4 (double checked everything). After trying things out, I think it is necessary to specify the "end of the column" like this: ``` sort -t . -n -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 ´´´ (this returns the proper result)

Answer (score 3):

Think that `sort -V` sorts your data as you want:

```
$ echo '2023.12.14
> 2020.10.4
> 2020.10.1
> 2020.5.18
> 2023.14.1
> 2021.1.1' | sort -V

2020.5.18
2020.10.1
2020.10.4
2021.1.1
2023.12.14
2023.14.1
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the only way this can be done with only `sort` is to use `-V`. But `-V` is not POSIX, and is not available in some sort implementations. So here's a POSIX (portable) solution:

```
awk -F . '{printf "%04d.%02d.%02d\n", $1,$2,$3}' dates-file |
sort |
awk -F . '{printf "%d.%d.%d\n", $1,$2,$3}'
```

awk transforms the fields to fixed length for sorting, then again transforms sorted data to the original format. This assumes these are dates.

Answer (score 0):

Not as great a solution as I hoped for - this one is specific to either `mawk-1` or `gawk`; limitations being :

- middle field and right most field has hard
  cap of `8^5-1`
- left most field allows up to `8^6-1`

The approach is to create a unified sorting key that sorts the same both numerically and in `ASCII` byte order, while allowing sufficient growth room for each of the 3 fields.

Pure duplicates are printed out on a `LIFO` basis

The 2 prefix `ascii control bytes` are used to prevent anywhere along the process flow, both within and beyond `awk`, attempting a purely numeric at insufficient floating point precision when it sees the hex that's potentially `80-bit` in size.

```
WHINY_USERS=1 {m,g}awk '        # this is a shell param for mawk-1
BEGIN {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        FS = "["(_=+(\
       OFS = "." ) )"]" 
} { __[\
    ____($_)]=$_ } END { for(_ in __) {
                            print __[_] } } 
function ____(___,__,_) {
    return  \
    sprintf("\31\17%.*s%.8X%.4X%.8X",(__="")*split(__,_),
    split(___,_,"[.]"), int((__=_[++__]*(___=(++__^++__\
           )^(__--+__))*___ + _[__]*___ + _[++__]) \
           )/(___+=___),__%___,___*___-___^(!___)-NR) 
}'
```

|

```
2020.5.18
2020.10.1
2020.10.4
2021.1.1
2023.12.14
2023.14.1
```